# "Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs" but no errors in Merged Manifest

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

We are trying to build an app where we keep getting this error:

`Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs`

We've tried to comment out literally everything in our manifest and also literally every dependency in our build.gradle.

When we open our `Manifest.xml` and open `Merged Manifest` and check we only see `Merge warnings` and no `Merge errors`. I've tried to introduce actual errors and they show up there. But whatever it's complaining about here is not showing. So I have no idea how to figure out WHAT is causing the manifest merger error. Is there any other way to make Android Studio tell us what it has issues with merging?

The feedback from this IDE is quite terrible sometimes ..

Answer (score -1):

Simply running `./gradlew :app:assembleDebug --stacktrace` in the project root gave me the same error but also indicated my error. Not sure why the editor can't show me the same.